# Help setting up NSD daemon (DNS server)

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, centos, centos5

While searching for a secure dns server I came across the [NSD project](http://www.nlnetlabs.nl/projects/nsd/).

I was really impressed by what seemed to me the best option out there that's open source.

One problem thought their 'tutorial' is really not beginner friendly.  I have basic DNS knoledge but what's in there is out of my league.

I need to have multiple sites on this CentOS server I've recently got my hands on.  They also need to receive email.

Details:
I have a master host and would love to set this in the way described in the rows that follow:

```
masterhost.com -> ns1.masterhost.com mail.masterhost.com www.masterhost.com
addonhost.com  -> ns1.masterhost.com mail.masterhost.com www.addonhost.com
```

And so on.

Any help in setting up this DNS server please?  All answers and suggestions are welcomed. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I know everyone's entitled to their own opinion, but have you tried BIND; I would argue it's the "best option out there that's open source". And there's a million how-to guides available and experts-a-plenty.

Answer (score 1):

NSD reads the same ([RFC 1035](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035)) format zone files as BIND, so presumably your first hurdle is knowing what a zone file looks like?

Learning that requires a full DNS tutorial, but for your zones you'll need something like:

```
$ORIGIN example.com
@        IN SOA   hostmaster ns1 (
                                    ... ; insert suitable values
                                 ) 
         IN NS    ns1
         IN MX 10 mail
ns1      IN A 192.0.200.1 ; put your name server's IP here
mail     IN A 192.0.200.2 ; put your mail server's IP here
www      IN A 192.0.200.3 ; put your web server's IP here
```

And in your `nsd.conf` file you just need:

```
zone:
    name: "example.com"
    zonefile: "example.com"
```

Answer (score -4):

Bind 9 does not have a good security record, so yes go NSD

Comment: On what are you basing this statement? It sounds like utter FUD. BIND 9 has been around a *very* long time (11+ years!).  In that time yes, security vulnerabilities have been found (show me one piece of 11-year-old software of any complexity that hasn't had vulnerabilities discovered), and more importantly they have been ***fixed***.  BIND is very widely deployed, and the ISC actively maintains the code, with an excellent track record of addressing vulnerabilities as they're discovered.